# Cant retreive a list column

Tags: list, sharepoint-online, caml-query

I am creating a hosted app in SharePoint. I want to retreive all the custom list from SharePoint and then from the custom lists I want to fetch column values. I got 2 columns with the names title and link. Link is a hyperlink column containing urls. My question is some of my custom lists doesnt have the column name "link" and some has. But I want to retreive those list that has that column. And title column is in every custom list. Some of the list has the column name "link" but with no values.

**Error message:** 0x800a138f - Runtime errors in JavaScript: Unable to retrieve the property get_url for a reference that is undefined or null

```
    function onSuccessItemFetch() {
    // Now you can access the array of SP.ListItemCollection
    for (var i = 0, length = listItemsCollection.length; i < length; i++) {
        var items = listItemsCollection[i];
        var enumerator = items.getEnumerator();

        while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
            var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
            if (typeof listItem.get_item('Link') != "undefined" && typeof listItem.get_item('Link') != null) {
            itemString += listItem.get_item('Title') + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "&nbsp" + "<a href='" + listItem.get_item('Link').get_url() + "'>" + "öppna formulär" + "</a>" + "</br>";  //oListItem.get_item('Datum')
            $('#divAllaListItems').html(itemString);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine when I want to retrieve all the custom list titles and the title column values.

Comment: Will it allow you to check whether `listItem.get_item('Link')` is defined before you try to set `itemString`?

Comment: If 1 list has not the column name link or has but with no value will it stop executing the code? why cant it just retreive items from list that has the column name "link"?

Comment: You're trying to call the `.get_url()` method on an object that doesn't exist, so yes that should stop execution. So you should check whether the object exists before using it. So something like `if(listItem.get_item('Link')) var linkURL = listItem.get_item('Link').get_url();`

Comment: I did like this what Eric Alexander showed me. `            while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
                if (typeof listItem.get_item('Link') != "undefined" || typeof listItem.get_item('Link') != null) {
                itemString += listItem.get_item('Title') + " " + "<a href='" + listItem.get_item('Link').get_url() + "'>" + "open link" + "</a>" + "</br>";  //oListItem.get_item('Datum')
                $('#divAllaListItems').html(itemString);
                }
            }`

Comment: But still I get the error message, maybe something is missing.

Comment: The OR statement you added is guaranteed to return true, because typeof listItem.get_item('Link') has to be either not equal to undefined or not equal to null. Perhaps you meant `if (typeof listItem.get_item('Link') != undefined && typeof listItem.get_item('Link') != null)`

Comment: Yes thank you my bad. But I still get the error message :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
  var listItem = enumerator.get_current();
  if(typeof listItem.get_item('Link') != "undefined"){
    itemString += listItem.get_item('Title') +  " " + "<a href='" + listItem.get_item('Link').get_url() + "'>" + "Open link" + "</a>" + "</br>";
    $('#divAllListItems').html(itemString);
  }          
}
```

But it would probably be more efficient to filter those out in the first place with a CAML query, but we don't know what is happening with the rest of your script.

Comment: I tried with your code but I get same error message.

Comment: @Eric you have undefined in quotes... is that correct?

Comment: Yes, or else I have been testing for undefined things wrong my whole JS life.

Comment: So how can I solve this issue. Your code should be enough to filter out "undefined" and "null" values.